# Changing variable in function dependant on getopts flag bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh, getopts

I have a bash script that finds connected devices and logs the serial port output to a file.
I am using getopts to choose the method of logging.
Two of the functions are the same except for one line.
I would like to change it to a single function with a variable for the single line that is different (my attempt is below) but have had no success. How can I do this with getopts?
Many thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to capture camera serial port logs via usb or UART.

file_name='DashcamLog'
#Date e.g: 20210204T120159 (ISO 8601)
current_date=$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S)
BAUDRATE='115200'
#change to reflect udev rules e.g /dev/h1*
BOARDS=(/dev/ttyUSB* /dev/ttyACM*)
screen="$(screen -Sdm $port_name -L -Logfile $new_file_name $i $BAUDRATE)"
minicom="$(screen -Sdm ${port_name} minicom -b ${BAUDRATE} -D ${i} -C ${new_file_name})"

usage() {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "Use $0 -a to use GNU screen to automatically capture logs on USB plug in"
    echo "Use $0 -s to use GNU screen to capture logs WITHOUT automatic capture on USB plug in."
    echo "Use $0 -m to use minicom to capture logs WITHOUT automatic capture on USB plug in."

}

#detects current + new devices + automatically starts logging
autoStartLog() {

    while true;do

        current_date=$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S)

        for i in $BOARDS; do

            port_name=${i#/dev/}

            if ! screen -ls | grep -o $port_name > /dev/null;then
                (
                    serial_no="$(udevadm info --attribute-walk $i | grep -m 1 ATTRS{serial})"
                    #file name e.g = DashcamLog_20210208T094013_peri_h1p1.log
                    new_file_name="${file_name}_${current_date}_${HOSTNAME}_${port_name}.log"
                    $screen
                    echo $port_name 'serial_no: ' $serial_no $new_file_name
                )
            fi

        done

    done

}

#detects current devices + starts logging using screen(-s)/minicom(-m)
startLog() {

    for i in $BOARDS; do
        (
            port_name=${i#/dev/}
            serial_no="$(udevadm info --attribute-walk $i | grep -m 1 ATTRS{serial})"
            new_file_name="${file_name}_${current_date}_${HOSTNAME}_${port_name}.log"
            $1
            echo $port_name 'serial_no: ' $serial_no $new_file_name
        )
    done

}


while getopts ":hmsa" opt; do
    case ${opt} in
        h)
          usage
          ;;

        a)
          autoStartLog
          ;;

        s)
          startLog $screen
          ;;

        m)
          startLog $minicom
          ;;

        \? )
          echo "Invalid Option: -$OPTARG" 1>&2
          usage
          exit 1
          ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))
```

Comment: Which line?  If I look at autoStartlog and startLog, they differ from one than 1 line.  Details are required for us to understand your question.  Is it the `while true` in autoStartLog? 
 If so, you could create a 3rd function that does the processing.  In autoStartLog, do the `while` and call this 3rd function.  In `startLog`, you just call the 3rd function once.  FYI, you do not need `( )` around your `if` or `for` blocks.  `do` and `done` are sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the tip about the brackets. Im trying to change ```$1``` in startLog, so that dependant on the option chosen it starts logging using different methods eg. ```./log.sh -s ``` calls startLog and uses screen to log and ```./log.sh -m``` calls startLog and uses minicom to log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a couple things, because I realized that explaining all little details in comments would be too long.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#script to capture camera serial port logs via usb or UART.

file_name='DashcamLog'
#Date e.g: 20210204T120159 (ISO 8601)
current_date=$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S)
BAUDRATE='115200'
#change to reflect udev rules e.g /dev/h1*
BOARDS=(/dev/ttyUSB* /dev/ttyACM*)

usage()
{
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "Use $0 -a to use GNU screen to automatically capture logs on USB plug in"
    echo "Use $0 -s to use GNU screen to capture logs WITHOUT automatic capture on USB plug in."
    echo "Use $0 -m to use minicom to capture logs WITHOUT automatic capture on USB plug in."
    exit 1
}

#detects current devices + starts logging using screen(-s)/minicom(-m)
startLog()
{
    for i in "${BOARDS[@]}"
    do
        port_name="${i#/dev/}"
        serial_no=$(udevadm info --attribute-walk "$i" | grep -m 1 "ATTRS{serial}")
        new_file_name="${file_name}_${current_date}_${HOSTNAME}_${port_name}.log"
        case "$1" in
            "screen")
                echo "PUT THE SCREEN COMMAND HERE"
                ;;
            "minicom")
                echo "PUT THE MINICOM COMMAND HERE"
                ;;
            \?)
                echo "Invalid Option: -$OPTARG" 1>&2
                usage
                ;;
        esac
        echo "$port_name serial_no:  $serial_no $new_file_name"
    done
}

while getopts ":hms" opt
do
    case "$opt" in
        h)
            usage
            ;;
        s)
            startLog screen
            ;;
        m)
            startLog minicom
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "Invalid Option: -$OPTARG" 1>&2
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))
```

Details:

- when you define variables screen and minicom, you had `"$( ... )"`.  The command inside `$()` is executed right then, not just later when you put the `$1` later.  That is why I removed that part and put the commands directly in the function.
- in startLog(), I reused a `case`.  An `if` could also be used.
- `BOARDS` is an array.  So when you do `$BOARDS`, without specifying an index, you only get the first item.  You have to do `${BOARDS[@]}` to process all items.
- in case you did not know, `BOARDS=(/dev/ttyUSB* /dev/ttyACM*)` will expand the `*` so BOARDS will be defined as all files `/dev/ttyUSB*` and all files `/dev/ttyACM*`.  It will not "stay" with the `*`.
- when you define a variable from another command (`var=$(command)`), you do not need to put `" "` around it.  It is also confusing since you should double-quote variables inside the `$()`, so you would have double-quotes inside other double-quotes.

I also put it in the code style I prefer, but that is flexible and subject to personal preferences.

You can put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ to validate the syntax.